# read values from text file in python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to include texts from a .text file in python and use them as values

in text file

```
LICENSE CODE = XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

ACTIVATION CODE = XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

and in python, I want to read the file with the open() command and identify license code and activation code and use the values in the code

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far

Comment: still, none looking for examples

Comment: You can use Regex operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex version:

```
import re


def find_regex_1(k, s):
    reg = f'{k}\s*=\s*(\S+)'
    return re.search(reg, s).group(1)


def read_configs(config_file):
    with open(config_file, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        license_code = find_regex_1('LICENSE CODE', content)
        activation_code = find_regex_1('ACTIVATION CODE ', content)
    return license_code, activation_code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    license_code, activation_code = read_configs('config.txt')
    print(license_code, activation_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if your text file is named as `input.text` and we you do as follows if you don't want to touch with regular expression,

```py
# read the file
with open("input.text", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # get LICENSE CODE
        if line.strip().startswith("LICENSE CODE"):
            license_code = line.strip().split(" = ")[-1]
        # get ACTIVATION CODE
        elif line.strip().startswith("ACTIVATION CODE"):
            activation_code = line.strip().split(" = ")[-1]
        else:
            print("parsing in progress")

# then you can use the license code and activation code do what you want.
```

Hope this helps a little.